# How to test login method using cakePHP 3.0 ?

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I want to test login method inside the controller, because I am a beginner in writing the tests and because I think that it is wise to test login method. if anyone has any objections let me know. Also I have found many solutions to test the login, but in cakephp 2.

```
  /**
 * Log the user into the application
 *
 * @return void|\Cake\Network\Response
 */
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is("post")) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $user = $this->addUsersAssociated($user);
            $user = $this->addUserDetailsToSession($user);
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }

        // User not identified
        $this->Flash->error(__d('cockpit', 'Your username or password is incorrect'));
    }
}
```

For example I want to test it when someone comes with wrong and right username/password. 
I am a total beginner and I would also like if someone can point me into the right direction (where is the quickest way to learn how to do this). I would like from someone who is independent to learn how to test my code. In other words I don't want to go to official documentation. (Have been there already)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out what happens, respectively what should happen in the different situations, and create tests with proper expectations.

Like on successful login, the user data is being set in the auth storage and a redirect header is being set, that's something you could test. Likewise on a non-successful login attempt, no user data is stored, no redirect header is being set, and a flash message is being rendered.

All these things can easily be checked in a controller integration test using either helper assertion methods, or even manually via the provided session and response objects, check:

- `$_requestSession`
- `$_response`
- `assertSession()`
- `assertRedirect()`
- `assertRedirectContains()`
- `assertResponse()`
- `assertResponseContains()`
- etc...

Here's two very basic examples:

```
namespace App\Test\TestCase\Controller;

use Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase;

class AccountControllerTest extends IntegrationTestCase
{
    public function testLoginOk()
    {
        $this->enableCsrfToken();
        $this->enableSecurityToken();

        $this->post('/account/login', [
            'username' => 'the-username',
            'password' => 'the-password'
        ]);

        $expected = [
            'id' => 1,
            'username' => 'the-username'
        ];
        $this->assertSession($expected, 'Auth.User');

        $expected = [
            'controller' => 'Dashboard',
            'action' => 'index'
        ];
        $this->assertRedirect($expected);
    }

    public function testLoginFailure()
    {
        $this->enableCsrfToken();
        $this->enableSecurityToken();

        $this->post('/account/login', [
            'username' => 'wrong-username',
            'password' => 'wrong-password'
        ]);

        $this->assertNull($this->_requestSession->read('Auth.User'));

        $this->assertNoRedirect();

        $expected = __d('cockpit', 'Your username or password is incorrect');
        $this->assertResponseContains($expected);
    }
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Testing > Controller Integration Testing](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#controller-integration-testing)**
- **[Cookbook > Testing > Controller Integration Testing > Testing Actions That Require Authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-actions-that-require-authentication)**
- **[Cookbook > Testing  > Controller Integration Testing > Assertion methods](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#assertion-methods)**

Comment: There is no method named `_requestSession`, only a property of that name - look closely at the example code. Also you're not supposed to write something into it, but to read from it. If you need to write something to the session for the request that you're going to test, then you should use the `session()` method, see http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#setting-up-the-request @Speedy

Comment: Thank you for a quick and really clean explanation. I have set the session data like you have described in the link above - $this->_requestSession->write([ 'Auth' => [ 'User' => [ 'id' => 1, 'username' => 'test@test.comt', 'password' => 'test', ] ] ]); What am I doing wrong ? 1) App\Test\TestCase\Controller\UsersControllerTest::testLogin Error: Call to a member function write() on null
App\Test\TestCase\Controller\UsersControllerTest::_requestSe‌​ssion()

Comment: Again, you're not supposed to write into `_requestSession`, that property is only populated _after_ making a request, ie it's only ment for inspecting what happened in the request. If you need to write something into the session _before_ the request is being made, then do it via `$this->session()` as shown in the linked docs. @Speedy

Comment: I get that I need to add $this->session([ 'Auth' => [ 'User' => [ 'id' => 1, 'username' => 'test@test.comt', 'password' => 'test', ] ] ]);
And I still get this as a response: "
There is no stored session data. Perhaps you need to run a request?"

Comment: I think the problem is with assertSession second parameter. 'Auth.User'

Comment: Are you still talking about testing the login? There is no need to write the user data into the session manually, that's what `$this->Auth->setUser()` will do  (at least in the default config), and it will store it under `Auth.User` unless configured otherwise. The error you are describing happens only when the `_requestSession` property hasn't been populated yet, ie when no request (like `$this->post()`) has been made yet. @Speedy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128877/discussion-between-speedy-and-ndm).

Comment: Yes, I am talking about testing. So I have basically copied/pasted your code to my machine and it should run from the beginning.

Comment: I know you're talking about testing, I was asking whether you're still talking about testing the login, because there should be no need to write anyhing into the session manually. It sounded as if you were trying to simulate a logged in user. The example here isn't more than just an example, you may need to adjust it, the URLs, the session storage path, etc. @Speedy

Comment: I was talking about testing the login method. 
BTW, I believe that I have discovered what was the problem. The problem was because I am not into my application just before testing the login method. It means that I need to set this session() in order to go in. At least that's why it wasn't working for the rest of the methods.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is really appreciated. I have also added my vote to your answer.